Expo react-native two way binding
I am experiencing a really annoying problem with the TextInput component of react-native. In development I test the app on web-browser and on my iPhone and some times on android virtual device. However the issue with the input only exists in the web-browser and it's like the input field loses focus when click on it to be able to start typing, which leads to be unable to get any client inputs :(. I suspect there is something wrong with the object state handling but not sure what exactly, any help will bi appreciated!
const Set = ({ exerciseID, placement }) => {
    const [setUnits, setSetUnits] = useState({
        reps: '',
        break: '',
        weight: '',
        exercise_id: exerciseID,
        placement
    });

    const handleChange = (val, prop) => {
        console.log(val, prop);
        setSetUnits({...setUnits, [prop]: val});
    }

    const handleSend = () => {
        createSet(setUnits);
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.setCard}>
            <View style={styles.cardNumber}>
                <Text style={styles.textLight}>{placement}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.cardContent}>
                <View style={styles.setUnitContainer}>
                    <TextInput
                    style={styles.textDark}
                    inputMode="numeric"
                    onChangeText={(val) => handleChange(val, 'reps')}
                    value={setUnits.reps}
                    />
                    <FontAwesome size={19} name="repeat" color="#0B3040" style={{paddingHorizontal: 5}}/>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.setUnitContainer}>
                    <TextInput
                    style={styles.textDark}
                    inputMode="numeric"
                    onChangeText={(val) => handleChange(val, 'weight')}
                    value={setUnits.weight}
                    />
                    <Ionicons name="barbell-sharp" size={22} color="#0B3040" style={{paddingHorizontal: 5}}/>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.setUnitContainer}>
                    <TextInput
                    style={styles.textDark}
                    inputMode="numeric"
                    onChangeText={(val) => handleChange(val, 'break')}
                    value={setUnits.break}
                    />
                    <FontAwesome size={20} name="clock-o" color="#0B3040" style={{paddingHorizontal: 5}}/>
                </View>
            </View>
            <Pressable onPress={handleSend}>
                <Text>Send</Text>
            </Pressable>
        </View>
    );
};

